# Ruby: method to print and neat an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, puts

I am not sure if this question is too silly but I haven't found a way to do it.

Usually to puts an array in a loop I do this

```
current_humans = [.....]
current_humans.each do |characteristic|
  puts characteristic
end
```

However if I have this:

```
class Human
  attr_accessor:name,:country,:sex
  @@current_humans = []

  def self.current_humans
    @@current_humans
  end

  def self.print    
    #@@current_humans.each do |characteristic|
    #  puts characteristic
    #end
    return @@current_humans.to_s    
  end

  def initialize(name='',country='',sex='')
    @name    = name
    @country = country
    @sex     = sex

    @@current_humans << self #everytime it is save or initialize it save all the data into an array
    puts "A new human has been instantiated"
  end       
end

jhon = Human.new('Jhon','American','M')
mary = Human.new('Mary','German','F')
puts Human.print
```

It doesn't work.

Of course I can use something like this

```
puts Human.current_humans.inspect
```

but I want to learn other alternatives!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use the method `p`. Using `p` is actually equivalent of using `puts` + `inspect` on an object.

```
humans = %w( foo bar baz )

p humans
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

puts humans.inspect
# => ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

But keep in mind `p` is more a debugging tool, it should not be used for printing records in the normal workflow.

There is also `pp` (pretty print), but you need to require it first.

```
require 'pp'

pp %w( foo bar baz )
```

`pp` works better with complex objects.

---

As a side note, don't use explicit return

```
def self.print  
  return @@current_humans.to_s    
end
```

should be

```
def self.print  
  @@current_humans.to_s    
end
```

And use 2-chars indentation, not 4.

Comment: Hi, I know this is old but I was just doing some Katas and came across this post. Why should `p` not be used (deeper explanation than the debugging one if possible please)? Also I used `p a` and `puts a.inspect` on an array called 'a' and only `p a` worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: I know 2 character indentation is standard in a lot of the ruby world.  As someone legally blind, I have to say 2 character indentation fails me badly.  Very hard to see the indent levels.